# Mac Chromeだとドラッグ＆ドロップ周りの処理でエラーが出る

Tags: javascript, macos

ウェブ上で動作するアプリケーションをHTML/CSS/JavaScriptで作成しています。

```
let id = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/html",event.target.id);  //ドロップされた要素のidを取得
let elm = document.getElementById(id);  //idからDOMを取得
let number = elm.getAttribute('data-question');  //DOMから何問目か取得
let answerArea = document.getElementById("answerArea_" + number);  //n問目の回答領域のDOMを取得
```

ドラッグ＆ドロップを使う処理を作成しました。
Windowsのブラウザ（Chrome/Edge/Firefox)とMacブラウザ（Safari)は問題なく動作が行えます。
しかし、MacのChromeだと3行目のnumberでエラーが発生します

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘getAttribute’ of null
```

これは、MacChromeのみに現れるエラーなのでしょうか？
それとも、プログラムコードに何か問題があるのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: このコード片だけだとなんとも言えないと思います。誰でも再現可能なコードを掲載してみてください。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: おそらく何らかの理由で`elm`にnullが入ってきているようです。そのためにはnullが入る原因を追求しなければいけませんが、理由としてはHTMLがおかしいもしくはgetDataで取得できてない等記載のコード以外のところに可能性が見受けられます。原因の特定のためにint32_tさんがおっしゃるように現象が再現するようにコードを追記してください